# return from incompatible pointer type in C (pointer to struct)

Tags: c, pointers, gcc-warning

Using the gcc compiler, I keep getting the warning:

```
file_system.c: In function ‘get_children’:
file_system.c:268:2: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  return children;
  ^
```

Here is the struct and function in question. The full code is at https://github.com/josephfortune/file-system . The intent is for the function to malloc-ate space for an array of structs, and return the pointer to that array. Any idea what is causing the warning?

```
struct FS_Directory
{
    uint8_t name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    uint32_t num_files;
    uint32_t num_children;
    uint32_t id;
}__attribute__((packed));

struct FS_Direcory* get_children( uint32_t id )
{
    uint32_t num_children, dir_offset;
    struct FS_Directory *children;

    num_children = dirs[get_index(id)].num_children;
    dir_offset = get_dir_offset( id );

    children = (struct FS_Directory*)malloc( num_children * sizeof( struct FS_Directory) );
    memcpy( children, &dirs[dir_offset], num_children * sizeof( struct FS_Directory ) );

    return children; 
}
```

Also know that the code runs perfectly, but to quote the book, Deep C Secrets, "There is a special place in Hades for those who ignore compiler warnings."

Comment: You have a typo in `FS_Direcory`. It should be `FS_Directory` — note the missing `t`.

Comment: But why does gcc allow that undeclared struct? The warning is only about the return type...

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` and friends and `void *` in general. C is not C++.

Comment: Yup, it was the typo. I wouldn't have thought that C would allow a function declaration to also serve as a struct definition.